# asp net core unit test model validator not covered non required fields

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core

I have added model validator to validate to model. it's covered only required fields but not others.

```
    public static class TestModelHelper
    {
        public static IList<ValidationResult> Validate(object model)
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
            Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, results, true);
            if (model is IValidatableObject)
            {
                (model as IValidatableObject).Validate(validationContext);
            }

            return results;
        }
    }

public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("emailId")]
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
}
```

using below command to generate the code coverage report.

dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage”

reportgenerator "-reports:./TestResults/{testresultsId}/coverage.cobertura.xml" "-targetdir:coveragereport" "-"reporttypes:Html"

in this model emailId only covered in code coverage. id and name are not covered.

Answer (score 0):

According to your codes, I don't found any validate attribute for the Name and Id, if you want to test validate result, you should put some validate attributes for them.

More details, you could refer to below codes and try again.

```
public class Employee
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [Range(0, 999.99)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(100)]
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("emailId")]
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
}
```